# Is there a C# method that stores all user generated events inside a form?

Tags: c#, events, logging, journal

I am a C# beginner, this is my fourth day programming in c#.
I am writing a GUI application that has a handful of buttons, and will then parse a large file, and show parsed data on the GUI combo box. For debugging purpose, and for improving the quality of my code, I would like to capture logs of user generated events, preferably just storing every button click, or combo box selection made (not every mouse movement, nor form getting focus, or other trivial events) in a text file.

Comment: there is no such method, you could register handlers for the events you are interested (like Button.Click, Combobox.SelectionChanged), and log to file in those handlers.

Comment: you can write method which will register an event handler for every event of all the controls. The handler should write events to the file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. You have thrown some key words help me better understand c# events.